# Get file details after `DownloadFileTaskAsync`

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am downloading a file from Uri like this:

```
var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(uri, filePath);
```

Is it possible to get the size and content type of the file directly after downloading it without any additional calls? (i.e., using similar download functions which returns details of the downloaded file, or any similar approach)

Comment: You shouldn't be using WebClient anyways. HttpClient is the recommended approach for http calls

Comment: I don't think it is possible based on source code of WebClient https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/webclient.cs,d6aef203f789360e,references

Comment: @Tseng, why is HttpClient better?

Comment: Generally HttpClient is more reusable and easier to handle (i.e. is thread-safe, handles the recycling of the connections etc.) and it returns a webresponse, which allows you to read the headers. You could use the Content-Length header, though its not really reliable (if the stream is compressed you get the compressed size). Of course you could wrap it in memory stream, iterate it yourself and count the size etc.